# How to change the background color of a tablecell on click with angular2?

Tags: angular, html-table, onclick, cell

I have a table and I would like to highlight and unhighlight a cell(change the background of the cell)of the table on click on the cell. My HTML looks like that:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let weekday of weekdays">
                <div>{{weekday}}</div>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr scope="row" *ngFor="let time of times"><td>{{time}}</td>
            <th scope="row" class = 'success' *ngFor="let weekday of weekdaysForClick"
             (click) = "onClick(weekday, time)" [ngClass] = "'active'" [class.selected]="weekday.clicked"></th> 
         </tr>
         </tbody>
</table>
```

and my class:

```
    weekdays : string[] = ['#','Monday', 'Thusday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday' ]
    times: string[] = ['8:30 - 9:15', '9:15 - 10:00', '10:15 - 11:00', '11:00 - 11:45', '12:30 - 13:15', '13:15 - 14:00', '14:15 - 15:00']
    weekdaysForClick : string[] = ['Monday', 'Thusday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday' ]
    wasClicked = false;

    onClick(weekday, time){

        this.wasClicked= !this.wasClicked;
        console.log(this.wasClicked)
        console.log(weekday, time);
    }
```

My problem is that right now the click event is not called on the item but rather called on the click. Whereever I click on my cells the was click chanching from false to true, but the cell item not holds it state.

What would be a good solution to register click event per cell item?

Comment: The problem is that you toggle the class with `weekday.selected` but you don't change the `weekday.selected` in your `onClick` method

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is either store an array of IDs (if you can select multiple lines), or a variable containing your ID (for a single selection).

Let's go with simple :

```
selected: '';

onClick(weekday, time){
  if(this.selected === weekday) {
    this.selected = '';
  } else {
    this.selected = weekday;
  }
}
```

In your HTML :

```
<th *ngFor="let weekday of weekdaysForClick"
         (click)="onClick(weekday, time)" [ngClass] = "'active'" [class.selected]="selected === weekday"></th>
```

Comment: I need single selection.

Comment: the replace selected with only a string, and not an array of strings.

Comment: I would like to be able to check if a cell has been clicked or not. With your implementation I can see which column was clicked but I can't see which item in the colomn. I want something when I click the cell it prints the state of the cell, on the way true=clicked, false= notclicked.

Comment: I don't even know what your array looks like to start with ... And your loops don't make the same length. If you have another question, don't ask in a comment, make another post or edit your original question.

Comment: How to change the background color of a table cell on click with angular2? This is my question. One table cell. "What would be a good solution to register click event per cell item?"

Comment: This is the exact same code duplicated. `[class.selected]="selectedDay === weekday && selectedTime === time"`.