# Angular + Bootstrap Tables with expandable rows

Tags: html, css, angular, responsive-design

In my current project, I have a table with a variable amount of columns and rows, due to being generated in an *ngFor directive and the data comes from the backend. Because of this and the fact that there might be a lot of text in a cell, there is an overflow and not all columns can be displayed.
I initially solved it by wrapping the overflow to a new line, but because it can be a lot of text, some rows can be too large.

My idea is to show some sort of preview where the overflow is hidden (similar to `overflow: ellipsis` but where the row can be expanded to show all the information. This way, the rows will have a reasonable size, but all the information can be displayed. The data is stored in an object where the column names are `string[]` and the data is `string[][]`.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table  table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let name of data.columnNames">{{name}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of data.data">
      <td *ngFor="let item of row">
        {{item}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How would you guys do this?

Comment: Tried bootstrap popover? Its similiar to a modal, but not that difficult and much faster. Its pretty optimal for a lot of text if you dont need any actions. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems to depend on a library though. I'd rather not use too many of those if I can help it.

Comment: I also use bootstrap without jquery, cause of angular. But Popper.js is a library which is mostly delivered with bootstrap and it also needs jquery. But yes, if you dont want to use jquery and the popper.js library, its not fitting for you. Then the modal solution could be the nearest alternative. But you also could use Nebular, its an Popover Angular Module. https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/popover/overview#nbpopoverdirective

Comment: I already have jQuery but not Popper.JS. I think I found a solution using only jQuery/JS. Normally, the overflow is handled by 'overflow: ellipsis'. When you click on therow though, with some jQuery, you switch that to showing all your data. Do you think that'll work?

Comment: Of course, you could just change the CSS-Property of the the CSS-Style overflow on an simple js-script `onClick`. But you also can use the angular directive `ngStyle`or better (what i would prefer) `ngClass`checked by a function if this class is applied or not. But for all of them, you need an id to change the style of the dynamically generated `td`. Best way to do this, is to send the row and column of the clicked `td` to the method you are calling. It would look like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49234982/5677688 I had something similiar and saved the clicked element in a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could leave the table with overflowing ellipsis and on click on the row you could open a modal that shows all data to improve the UX in all screen resolutions.

Comment: I just realized, wouldn't it be possible/better to have switch onClick between showing all the data and 'overflow: ellipsis' using a little JS?